# Show that for any $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $p$ prime: $(a^p+b^p)^{p^2}\equiv a+b \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that for any $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $p$ prime:
$$(a^p+b^p)^{p^2}\equiv a+b \pmod p$$
Using the binomial expansion, I found that $$(a^p+b^p)^{p^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{p^2}\binom{p^2}{n}\;a^{np}\;b^{(p^2-n)p}$$
But $$\binom{p^2}{n}\equiv0 \pmod p$$ for $n\not= 0,p^2$, so:
$$(a^p+b^p)^{p^2}\equiv a^{p^3}+b^{p^3}\equiv (a+b)^{p^3} \pmod p$$

If $a+b$ coprime with $p$ then $$(a+b)^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p \Rightarrow (a+b)(a+b)^{p^3-1}\equiv (a+b)(a+b)^{(p-1)(p^2+p+1)}$$
$$\equiv (a+b)(a+b)^{p^2+p+1}$$

But I'm stuck there. Also, is my progress correct?

Comment: How do you prove $\dbinom{p^2}n\equiv 0\pmod p$?

Comment: The sentence starting with "If $a+b$ not coprime with $p$" makes no sense, to be honest. You need them to be coprime to have $(a+b)x+py=1$. And, even that equality does not give $a+b\cong 1\pmod{p}$. It gives $ax\cong 1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: yeah sorry I'm a bit tired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler solution: work in $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$.

You have to prove that in this ring $(a^p+b^p)^{p^2}=a+b$.

Now, it is known that $a^p=a$ (this is essentielly *Little Fermat*). Thus
$$(a^p+b^p)^{p^2}=(a+b)^{p^2}=\bigl((a+b)^p\bigr)^p=(a+b)^p=a+b.$$

Comment: I feel dumb having overlooked that fact from little Fermat now that I think about it, thanks.

Comment: You have a typo in the last equation. $p^2$ should be on the top of $(a+b)$

Comment: @E. Girgin: Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 2):

I think, you have done it, except the minor point at the end.
$$(a+b)(a+b)^{(p-1)(p^2+p+1)}$$
$$(a+b)\left({(a+b)^{(p-1)}}\right)^{(p^2+p+1)}$$
$$\equiv (a+b)\left(1\right)^{p^2+p+1}$$
$$\equiv (a+b)$$